# New Macbook Pro stolen - can I get it back?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I got myslef a new macbook pro 13 and left it in my car, it was in a plastic bag with the bill inside it. when I came back it was gone !!! I hadn't even open the box ! so no softwares or tracking things installed.

is there anything I can do ? I have already informed the police.

but I can get a serial number of the machine that I bought, is there a way / anyway I can get it back !

Comment: Sorry mate nothing you can do about that one doubt you got insurance for it

Comment: just bought it, no no :(

Comment: You can report it stolen, or tell someone at the apple store, they have the serial number on file so they might be able to do something but it's unlikely. Also when you buy electronics and you're not in your car with it leave it in the boot(trunk) of the car.

Comment: Did you buy it on card? If so you have a record of the purchase

Comment: yes i do ? what next ?

Comment: left it in the car? mate, april's fool was several days ago. who the hell leaves a Macbook Pro alone inside a car? it will be a LOT hard to recover it, mainly since you were careless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IANAL, but the commonly accepted procedure is to report the theft to your local law enforcement agency, and making sure to get a copy of your report. You might have to do this in person. Then you bring your copy to your insurance broker (assuming you have some variety of "items I own unexpectedly lost value or disappeared"-insurance (pretty common where I live) or --if you are currently traveling-- travel insurance) and make an appropriate insurance claim. If you're lucky, you can do this electronically or via mail.

The end result should ideally be that you receive [the value of your Macbook Pro minus whatever was agreed upon previously in you insurance policy] as a cash payment from your insurance broker, and the legal ownership of your Macbook Pro (which is currently held by whoever stole it) is transferred to the insurance broker.

The procedure might vary a bit in different countries. Consult your insurance broker, a lawyer or your local law enforcement agency if you need specific advice.

Comment: is there a way to get a machine back ?

Comment: Find the one who stole it? What do you expect? There's no magic tracking of stolen (new) devices @smi

Comment: @smithwatson - You report it stolen.  If the police recover a laptop with the serial number you should get it back.  Honestly...This is the reason people should use credit cards ( provided they pay the balance in full ) on purchases like this.  This allows you to report it to the credit card company.  I know American Express has everal policies that favor the customer.

Comment: @Ramhound Although I don't think they'll be too excited about it being stolen because it was left in a car.